# Listbox; How to search as type, but select top value automatically

Tags: vba, ms-access

When I type into a search box (textbox) my list box will update due to the following criteria within my listbox query;

Like "*" & [Forms]![UptimeAARecord]![txtSearchItems].[text] & "*"

The list box updates from a OnChange event which the listbox as the user types into the "search" textbox. Everything is working perfectly, however I would like to know how can I make my code select the very top value upon this same OnChange event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your listbox is sorted as wanted: This selects the first value.

```
If Me.myListbox.ListCount > 0 Then
    Me.myListbox.Selected(0) = True
End If
```